# How to handle concurrency in a slow flask api?

Tags: python, flask, concurrency, microservices

We have a flask api solution which has an average response time of 5 secs under no load. The api doesnt have async support. But we want to scale this api so that it can handle 10 request per second with atleast 50 concurrent clients. What should be approach and which server configuration should we use to get this concurrency ? The solution will run as a microservice in kubernetes. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

P.S - The reason is databrick driver which takes atleast 70 % of the total time of the response (opening connection ,fetching the data back, and closing the connection). And also the databrick driver doesn't have any asynchronous interface that's why we are thinking what we can do from the server configuration to increase the concurrency. We have tried asyncio to gain concurrency but that won't help as the databrick driver doesn't have any async support.

Comment: suggest you use asyncio. it's a bit hard but the learning curve worth the advantages

Answer (score 0):

Profile it and find why it is running so slowly? There isn't enough information here to tell you what is wrong or what to do.

Comment: The reason is databrick driver which takes atleast 70 % of the total time of the response (opening connection ,fetching the data back, and closing the connection). And also the databrick driver doesn't have any asynchronous interface that's why we are thinking what we can do from the server configuration to increase the concurrency.